# Brainstorming Objective-C runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, objective-c-runtime

Every time I go back into understanding Objective-C runtime, I end up messing my brain. As far as I understand (from reading some awesome write-ups like [Metaclasses](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/04/14/objc_explain_Classes_and_metaclasses.html), [Obj-C Runtime](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.in/2010/01/understanding-objective-c-runtime.html)) Objective-C classes are actually class objects e.g. NSString is itself an object to its Root Meta Class. Moreover its so called ivar "**isa**" pointer keeps all the basic details like super class, method lists, name etc. Below are some questions based on this theory only -

(1). Check the current declaration of objc/runtime.h and you'll find the following struct declaration:

```
    struct objc_class {
        Class isa  OBJC_ISA_AVAILABILITY;

>     #if !__OBJC2__
        Class super_class                                        OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
        const char *name                                         OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
        long version                                             OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
        long info                                                OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
        long instance_size                                       OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
        struct objc_ivar_list *ivars                             OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
        struct objc_method_list **methodLists                    OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
        struct objc_cache *cache                                 OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
        struct objc_protocol_list *protocols                     OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
> 
> **#endif**

    } OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
```

I hope this means that from Objective-C 2.0 all there is available in this struct is "**isa**" pointer. This seems to fade all the logic from this runtime theory. Where does these details like super class, method list etc. stored now?

---

(2). Technically **isa** is pointer to struct **objc_class** which itself has **isa** as its member. So when I try accessing (in AppDelegate for say):

> ```
>      NSLog(@"class isa ptr %@", isa->isa);
> ```

or

```
NSLog(@"class isa %@", ((Class)[NSString class])->name);
```

I receive a compile-time error:

- Member reference base type 'Class' is not a structure or union.

Why? I think its the correct syntax to access structures members

---

(3). Printing 'Class' (I'm referring to `typedef struct objc_class *Class`) object on console using NSLog displays Objective-C class' name.

```
NSLog(@"NSObject class %@", [NSObject class]);
```

How is that so? class is a class method that returns 'Class' object. If class name was to be printed, it should be printed like this:

```
NSLog(@"NSObject class %@", ((Class)[NSObject class])->name);
```

Help me figure out what is there that I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### (1) Where does these details like super class, method list etc. stored now?

In ObjC 2.0 all the class details are private implementation details. Maybe the data layout remained actually the same, maybe not.

#### (2) Why can't I access the field `name`?

The header file you quoted says that in ObjC 2.0 only the `isa` pointer is there, all other stuff has gone away.

#### (3) Why does `NSLog` print `[NSString class]` as `NSString`?

Because `NSLog`, like `-[NSString stringWithFormat:]` invokes the `description` method onto the object provided. Obviously, the method `+[Class description]` returns the name of the class.

Comment: I'd disagree unless there's a proof. Please see my Ques. 2 again, it states that isa->isa is also giving compile time error. Also, there is no such "description" method that can be called on Class. Look at class it is a typedef of structure pointer typedef struct objc_class *Class. How will you call any method on it.

Comment: `NSObject` has a method `+description`. This method gets called by `+[NSString stringWithFormat:]`. You can call a method on a `Class` like this: `objc_msgSend([NSString class], @selector(description))`. This is what `[NSString description]` compiles down to. It's a bit rude from you to downvote my post, I have used all of these runtime methods productively so often, I know by experience what is possible and what not and how things work. If you want a proof, read the docs.

Comment: But if you look at C perspective 'Class' is in actual typedef struct objc_class *Class. What does it actually mean to call a method on 'Class'. It's quite strange to me.

Comment: all objects are underneath just C structs. calling a method means calling `objc_msgSend(self, sel, ...)`. And that method looks up self->isa to get the class pointer, then it looks up the method in the method list inside that Class object. And objc_msgSend doesn't use the definition in objc/runtime.h, it has its own private definition. So calling [obj doThis] is a bit like calling obj->isa->methodList["doThis"](obj, @selector(doThis))

Comment: good explanation. Thanks. Please justify me your  ques 2 answer too. I cannot access isa->isa too. Moreover, if name is not available then compiler error should be different

Comment: hmm... good question. objc_class is deprecated says my compiler. I cannot even get an isa-pointer. It says I should use object_getClass() instead. `isa` is deprecated too, and it just does not work. You can hack it though: Use `void *get_isa(void *something) { return *((void **)something); }` to deref the isa-pointer. The engineers who made that just don't want us to mess around in these C-structs, that's all I think.

Comment: Hmm...But Passing in isa to the method you defined will give same compiler error?

Comment: yeah, you cannot do `obj->isa`, only `get_isa(obj)`. and instead of `get_isa(obj->isa)` you have to do `get_isa(get_isa(obj))`

Comment: Where did you get that `isa` variable from, btw?

Comment: isa is basically an ivar of NSObject. So if you're writing your code in any class that is inherited from NSObject, just access directly like isa. I hope this is what you wanted to ask.